# UITextField drawPlaceholderInRect not called when using setText

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I created a custom subclass of UITextField, where a background and placeholder text color is set.
The drawPlaceholderInRect is called fine when I don't set the text of my textfield (in the viewcontroller).

But when I call this method:

```
[self.txtEmail setText:@"test@test.com"];
```

the drawPlaceholderInRect method isn't called anymore. The text of the textfield is setting fine, but the method is not called. Since it is called when the text is not set, the delegates etc should be fine.

What on earth is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name suggests, the method `drawPlaceholderInRect` is to draw the placeholder text, i.e., the text if there isn't any text set. Since you are setting the text of the field, no placeholder is needed and thus, the method is not called.

Comment: Ofcourse, how could I be so stupid. I put my code to set the backgroundColor in the initWithCoder, and it works fine now. Many thanks!